# Firebase 3 orderByChild not working with ionic2

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I am trying to retrieve data from my firebase database but I am not possible to sort the data by a child value.

```
data.db.orderByChild('likes').on('value', data => {
            this.posts = data.val();
            this.posts = Object.keys(this.posts).map(key => this.posts[key])
            console.log(this.posts);
        });
```

Here is my Service for data

```
this.db = firebase.database().ref('/posts');
```

and here my structure of the database

```
{
   "posts": {
      "1473631200000": {
         "date": "12.02.2016",
         "imageUrl": "http..."
         "userId": "id",
         "likes": 20
      }
      "1473804000000": {
         "date": "12.08.2016",
         "imageUrl": "http..."
         "userId": "id",
         "likes": 284
      }
   }
}
```

I am possible to retrieve the data but I cant sort them by the value of likes. I just want the top posts to be more in the front.

Comment: i think likes should be integer, not string.

Comment: Sorry my fault indeed it is integer but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute a query against the Firebase Database, it returns a DataSnapshot. That snapshot contains the keys, values *and the order* of the children.

When you retrieve a `val()` from the snapshot, it converts it to dictionary of keys and values. It loses the ordering in this case.

To keep the ordering, loop over the DataSnapshot using `forEach` and only then get the value:

```
data.db.orderByChild('likes').on('value', data => {
    this.keys = [];
    this.posts = [];
    data.forEach(child => {
        this.keys.push(child.key);
        this.posts.push(child.val());
    });
    console.log(this.posts);
});
```

Comment: Thank you it works. How do I retrieve the data backwords? It shows me the posts with 0 likes first

Comment: I recommend reading a few of the answers in this list: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+reverse+order